# When I create a bridge and make my ethernet port the bridge's master, what device does the kernel use for sending and receiveing

Tags: routing, ip, bridge

If I create a bridge and set its master to my ethernet port, how does the kernel send and receive packets?

```
# Create the bridge
ip link add name br0 type bridge
ip link set dev br0 up

# Make eno1 the upstream connection for the bridge
ip link set eno1 master br0
```

I presumed that kernel sends and receives on eno1, and does kernel magic to decide what's meant for the local host and what needs to be forwarded to the bridge.

However, I'm wondering if `eno1` doesn't need (or shouldn't have) an ip address, and that the old ip will only work until the dhcp lease expires.

Should I remove the ip address from `eno1`, then create a virtual ethernet device that's connected to the bridge? The kernel would use the virtual ethernet device, which will send packets to the bridge, and out eno1? Or is there indeed magic that just does things for me?

Comment: if you have ifstat installed, you will see that the traffic goes from br0 to eno1